# changing or removing the Headers and Footers from mailing templates

Tags: civimail, message-templates, header-footer

Does anyone know if it's possible to stop a mailing template from using the default headers and footers?

I'd like to know if it's possible to disable the headers and footers for the template (if that can be done by assigning "empty" headers and footers, then I'd like to know about assigning different ones than the default.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the send mail Templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly I don't follow the question, but using CiviMail you can avoid the need for using Headers or Footers by ensuring that you include all the required tokens in the template itself. You can also 'edit' the existing default Header and Footer and set them to not be default, hence when you then use your template in CiviMail, no header or footer will be automatically included, and none will be required.

Comment: You can also 'edit' the existing default Header and Footer and set them to not be default" Excellent - Thank You.

Comment: If my answer helped would you pls give it the big green tick so StackExchange records it as 'answered'. thanks

Comment: Thanks Pete - couldn't find it for a while... it's grey before I click it!